# how to view full calendar using index file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Following is the code that I am used to display full calendar view. But it is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="scheduler.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="scheduler.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to init fullcalendar in a script tag on the end of the body using

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
</script>
```

Also, are you sure the script and stylesheet files are on the same directory of your page?

You can find documentation on [FullCalendar Docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/)

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply.What we are trying to achieve is creating a web app using full calendar. We are newbies into html and css things, so we first needed to see how this full calendar UI looks in a web page. We downloaded full calendar from the website but they hv segrigated html and css files in to different files which we hv not worked before and plz need help on that . Thanks once again.

Comment: Will get to you in a couple of hours

Comment: Hi, got to know what went wrong! We were trying to launch (.html) files separately from directory. Then 1 of my friends explained me that we need to open whole directory in an editor(I have Brackets ). After opening in it and on running a .html file it was showing the page. What happened = When we launched the single (.html) file it wasn't able to open/access the referred (.js) ,(.css) and (.html) files bcoz of path given unlike when opened in Editor.Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Glad it worked out. More information about path here http://miraimages.com/portfolio/html-paths-explained/